# Juste GET Request work with POSTMAN, POST Request return 403Forbidden : Spring Boot mongoDB (Postman Test)

Tags: spring, mongodb, post, spring-data, postman

Can you explain to me how can I make a POST Request in postman for add a new user to my user collection.

The problem is that i can add a user with Get Request, but POST Request return 403 Forbidden.

can you tell me how can i authorize POST requests?

I tried this solution in my Controller, but nothing is fixed :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.POST })
```

in spring-boot I have 3 entities: User, Center and Role

the relationship between them and the following:

**Class User :**

```
@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private long telephone;
    private long idCCMS;
    private String matricule;

    @DBRef
    private Centre centres;

    @DBRef
    private Role roles;
```

**Class Role:**

```
@Document
public class Role {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String role;
    private String description;

    @DBRef
    private Collection<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Class Centre**

```
@Document
public class Centre {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String reference;
    private String libelle;

    @DBRef
    private Collection<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

**My Repository :**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    List<User>findByMatricule(String matricule);
    User findByLogin(String login);
    List<User>findByNom(String nom);
    List<User>findByPrenom(String prenom);
}
```

**My Controller :**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.POST })
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:4200" })
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

//  @Autowired
//  private MongoTemplate mtUser;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    @Query(value = "{}", fields = "{'objectContentAsJson':0}")
    public Iterable<User> getall() {
        return (userRepo.findAll());
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public User save(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }
```

To add a user in my database I added this code in the body of postman :

```
{
    "id": "5e319750fcf3c73b589b6211",
    "login": "aaaa",
    "password": "aaaa",
    "nom": "aaaa",
    "prenom": "aaaa",
    "telephone": 97408105,
    "idCCMS": 123456,
    "matricule": "mat123",
    "centres": "5e319dd0730b1659d5910e0c",
    "roles": "5e319dd0730b1659d5910e0d"
}
```

Is it correct to add the Center ID and the Role ID in the center and role fields of the json code?

[image]

In Postman I added in the "Authorization" Type "Basic Auth" section I added the default username of Spring Security "Use"' and the password generated by my Application Server :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The response is `401 Unauthorized` which means you need to add Username and Password to your request.

Comment: I believe you've added Spring Security dependency in pom.xml. If so, check the logs printed in your console to a generated random password. Use the generated password and username as `user`.

Comment: @Mansoor Yes, i use Spring Security, I've this dependancy. In Postman I added in the "Authorization" Type "Basic Auth" section I added the default username of Spring Security "Use"' and the password generated by my Application Server

Comment: Can you add your controller method?

Answer (score 0):

The response is `401 Unauthorized` which means you need to add Username and Password to your request.

In your pom.xml see if you've dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If above is true, Spring security will generate a random password. Use that along with username as `user` to authenticate in Postman.

Comment: Yes, i use Spring Security, I've this dependancy. In Postman I added in the "Authorization" Type "Basic Auth" section I added the default username of Spring Security "Use"' and the password generated by my Application Server.

Comment: `user` is the default username.

Comment: Yes I used the default name of Spring Security, because until now I have not made any configuration for spring security, I left it as it is

Comment: is my method correct ?

 @PostMapping("/add")
 public User save(@RequestBody User user) {
  return userRepo.save(user);
 }

Comment: Please edit your question and add the controller method there. New visitors will know about the changes.

Comment: The request with GET work Correctly, but with POST i get 403 Forbidden error ?